# I want to display from date and to date on the frontend container from the json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, javascript-objects

I have 4-5 containers in my html. Refer the sample code below.

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="subContainer">
    <%--<button id="testdata" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server">Refresh</button>--%>
      <div class="divContainer">
        <div class="appContainer"> Application 1 </div>
        <div class="hiddenContainer" id="app1" data-jsonData="0" hidden>
          <div class="lblContainer">Application 1</div>
          <div class="dateContainer">
            <div class="fromDateContainer"> <label for="fromDate">From date</label> <span class="fromDate">From Date Val</span> </div>
            <div class="toDateContainer"> <label for="toDate">To date</label> <span class="toDate">To date val</span> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="timeContainer"> <label for="timeLeft">Time remaining</label> <span>Time remaining value</span> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="appContainer" data-jsonData="1"> Application 2 </div>
        <div class="hiddenContainer" id="app2" data-jsonData="1" hidden>
          <div class="lblContainer">Application 2</div>
          <div class="dateContainer">
            <div class="fromDateContainer"> <label for="fromDate">From date</label> <span class="fromDate">From Date Val</span> </div>
            <div class="toDateContainer"> <label for="toDate">To date</label> <span class="toDate">To date val</span> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="timeContainer"> <label for="timeLeft">Time remaining</label> <span>Time remaining value</span> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I using the below javascript code. First I use the json data which is an array of objects.

Json data sample:

```
0: {
  app_Name: 'Application 1',
  to_Date: '2023-11-07T16:48:00',
  from_Date: '2023-11-09T14:47:00'
}
1: {
  app_Name: 'Application 2',
  to_Date: '2023-11-23T15:57:00',
  from_Date: '2023-11-24T15:57:00'
}
```

In the below javascript code I am trying to add ids dynamically to the containers in html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let jsonData;
  let fromDate = [];
  let toDate = [];

  function loadData(data) {
    jsonData = data;
    console.log(jsonData)
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let appCon = document.getElementsByClassName("appContainer");
    let hiddenCon = document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenContainer");
    // Assuming you want the first element with the class 'hiddenContainer' 
    for (let i = 0; i < appCon.length; i++) {
      fromDate.push({
        id: `fromDateId${i}`
      });
      toDate.push({
        id: `toDateId${i}`
      });
      appCon[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        let appDetails = this.dataset.jsonData;
        hiddenCon[i].removeAttribute("hidden"); /*console.log(appDetails)*/
        displayData(i)
      });
      appCon[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        hiddenCon[i].setAttribute("hidden", "true");
        // hideDetails(i); 
      });
    }
  })
  function displayData(index) {
    if (fromDate.length > index && toDate.length > index) {
      let appData = jsonData[index];
      if (appData) {
        console.log(appData);
        let fromDateId = fromDate[index].id;
        let toDateId = toDate[index].id;
        console.log("Generated Ids:" + fromDateId, toDateId) let fromDateElem = document.querySelector(`#${fromDateId}`);
        let toDateElem = document.querySelector(`#${toDateId}`);
        console.log(fromDateElem, toDateElem);
        if (fromDateElem && toDateElem) {
          let fromDateElemValue = fromDateElem.querySelector('.fromDate');
          let toDateElemValue = toDateElem.querySelector('.toDate');
          console.log(fromDateElemValue, toDateElemValue);
          if (fromDateElemValue && toDateElemValue) {
            fromDateElemValue.textContent = appData.from_Date;
            toDateElemValue.textContent = appData.to_Date;
          } else {
            console.log("One or more value elements not found.");
          }
        } else {
          console.log("One or more elements not found.");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("App data is null.");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I get stuck here because fromDateElemValue and toDateElemValue returns null in the console.

Comment: Hey, please format your code blocks. I can not read the code when it is in one line only.

Comment: I think in your js, you're pushing objects with IDs into the fromDate and toDate arrays. However, I do not see if these IDs are actually being assigned to the HTML elements. When not, querySelector will not find them.

Comment: How can I assign them?

Comment: Maybe sth like this:

for (let i = 0; i < appCon.length; i++) {
    let hiddenContainer = hiddenCon[i];
    let fromDateContainer = hiddenContainer.querySelector('.fromDateContainer');
    let toDateContainer = hiddenContainer.querySelector('.toDateContainer');

    // Set IDs
    fromDateContainer.id = `fromDateId${i}`;
    toDateContainer.id = `toDateId${i}`;
    
    // Rest
}

Comment: Actually I want to display the from and to date in span where it's written from date value. So I need to change the query selector right? Is rest of my code correct?